# ui router dynamically changing parent template based on fromState

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

I have a modal with a specific route /case/subpage but I want the parent template to match the last state template so it looks like its just an overlay on the current page.  Example: user clicks from Contact Us, the parent template is contact us while the state is /case/subpage

Here is where I'm at, I can hardcode and get this to work but I wanted a way to get the previous state in templateProvider but fromState only works on $rootScope

```
.state 'case',
    url: '/case'
    templateProvider: ($http) ->
        templateName = '/views/contact.html'
        console.log(templateName)
        return $http.get(templateName).then (tpl) ->
            console.log('success',tpl);
            tpl.data
    controller:'MainCtrl',
.state 'modal',
    url: ''
    abstract:true,
    parent:'case',
    onEnter: ($modal) ->
        $modal.open
          templateUrl: '/views/case/modal.html',
          controller: 'ModalCtrl',
          animation: true,
          size: 'sm'
        return
```